# populating List<dynamic> from an Enumerable.Range or a List<int>

Tags: c#, list, linq, ienumerable

Currently, I use the following C# code to populate a `List<dynamic>` object with a range of integers:

```
var x = new List<dynamic>();
foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, 100)) x.Add(i);
```

Is there a more lucid way of doing this? I tried

```
x = Enumerable.Range(0, 50).ToList();
```

and also

```
x = Enumerable.Range(0, 50).ToList<dynamic>();
```

but both result in type checking errors, presumably because C# has no automatic cast to `List<dynamic>` from `List<T>`.

Note that I am interfacing with an external library, so simply using `List<int>` instead of `List<dynamic>` is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input really is a `List<int>` (or a `List<T>`, even), the following saves on allocation:

```
List<int> li;
var x = new List<dynamic>(li.Count);
x.AddRange(li.Cast<dynamic>());
```

If you find yourself doing this a lot, this is a prime candidate for an extension method:

```
static class CollectionExtensions {
    public static List<dynamic> ToDynamicList<T>(this ICollection<T> collection) {
        var result = new List<dynamic>(collection.Count);
        result.AddRange(collection.Cast<dynamic>());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Using `ICollection` rather than `IList` doesn't add a lot, but hey, `ICollection` is the one introducing `Count`, so why not.

Otherwise, using `.ToList()` after a `.Cast<dynamic>()` works fine.

Comment: Thanks, I've settled for `Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Cast<dynamic>().ToList()` which seems to be the cleanest looking solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ like this:

```
var x = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(i => (dynamic) i).ToList();
```

Comment: or `Cast<dynamic>()`, which is (arguably) neater.